# Join keys and values from Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

Is there a way to quickly (i.e. without using `foreach`) concat the following `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> g = new Dictionary<string, string>();
g.Add("K", "k1");
g.Add("L", "l1");
```

into

```
"K=@K,L=@L"
```

and what about getting this result: `"K=k1,L=l1"` ?

I am playing a little with `String.Join`, but that doesn't seem to do what I want.

Some background: I have a list of key/value pairs I want to either INSERT in my database `(...keys...) VALUES (...values...)` or UPDATE a records `...,key=value, ...`.

Comment: can you please add your `string.Join(...)` thing?? that's the most important part of the question...

Comment: @cramopy I have nothing more than `String.Join(",", g.Keys)` which is not what I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily with LINQ, it still is using `foreach` under the covers so it won't be any "faster" but it should be easy to read.

```
Dictionary<string, string> g = new Dictionary<string, string>();
g.Add("K", "k1");
g.Add("L", "l1");

var keys1 = g.Select(x=>String.Format("{0}=@{0}", x.Key));
var result1 = String.Join(",", keys1);
Console.WriteLine(result1);

var keys2 = g.Select(x=>String.Format("{0}={1}", x.Key, x.Value));
var result2 = String.Join(",", keys2);
Console.WriteLine(result2);
```

[<kbd>Run Code</kbd>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uiFWXo)

The first thing we do is we make a `IEnumerable<String>` of the items we want, we then use `string.Join` to combine that IEnumerable in to a single string.

**EDIT:**
If you are updating in to a database I recommend dropping this approach and try out some ORM libraries like Entity Framework or NHibernate. They do all this work for you and make it much easier to work with objects and not worry about generating dynamic queries.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on the framework. I will certainly consider that. This specific piece of code is extremely dynamic though (it is a generic XML reader), so I hope those frameworks can help me there as well.

Comment: [There are a lot of them out there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#.NET) Take a look around, one might fill your needs.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest code I can think of is

```
string res = string.Join("\n", g.Select(p => "K=" + p.Key + ",L=" + p.Value));
```

This results in

```
K=K,L=k1
K=L,L=l1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an extension class on the dictionary as well.  This runs the same but then lets you do something simple like

```
g.ToKeyValueString("{0}=@{1}", ",");
```

The Helper class

```
internal static class DictionaryHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a string of key value pairs in the format k1=v1,k2=v2,...
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="dictionary"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string ToKeyValueString<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        return ToKeyValueString(dictionary, "{0}={1}", ",");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a string of key value paris in the format k1=v1{separator}kk2=v2...
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="dictionary"></param>
    /// <param name="seperator">The string separator for the pairs</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string ToKeyValueString<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, string seperator)
    {
        return ToKeyValueString(dictionary, "{0}={1}", seperator);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a string of key value pairs in the specified format with the specified separator
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="dictionary"></param>
    /// <param name="format">The format string for the key value pairs</param>
    /// <param name="separator">The string separator for the pairs</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string ToKeyValueString<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, string format, string separator)
    {
        var pairs = dictionary.Select(c => string.Format(format, c.Key, c.Value));
        return string.Join(separator, pairs);
    }
}
```